# Trying to get property of non-object when using Auth::username

Tags: laravel-5

I got error when my `views.blade.php` has this code :

```
{!!Auth::user()->name!!}
```

And I want to show the name ,who was online in the admin.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the name inside controller when returning to your desired view, for example inside controller when you return to your view it should be something like:

```
return view('myView', [
            'name' => Auth::user()->name,
        ]);
```

And in your blade view, you can use it like `{{ $name }}`

Cheers,,

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting that error then there is currently no authenticated user or if you are on 5.2 it could mean you don't have the 'web' middleware applied to that route.

`Auth::user()` will return null when there is no authenticated user or no session store.